# jQuery getScript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example i have script

```
$.getScript('http://jquery.com/files/social/js/jquery.tabs.js',function(data){console.log(data)})
```

In returns `undefined`, but if i load in this way:

```
$.getScript('/social/js/jquery.tabs.js',function(data){console.log(data)})
```

It will return me contents of my script. Is it possible to fix?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out this [site](http://www.pacecode.com/blog/2011/09/01/cross-domain-communications-with-jsonp-using-javascript-and-jquery/), they have given some real time example for JSONP Req

Answer (score 3):

You are having a CrossDomain problem, you can not do ajax request to pages with different domains/ports. Check JSONP, jquery supports it to some extent: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Please take into account you might need to control or at least support from the server side depending on what you want to do.